# Prove that two metrics are complete and equivalent on the same set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a question regarding completion of metric spaces on open intervals (I posted similar questions on the community before, but did not receive a good answer, sorry):

**Problem:** Show that $D_1(x,y)=\left|\tan(\frac{\pi x}{2})-\tan(\frac{\pi y}{2})\right|$ and $D_2(x,y)=|x-y|+\left|\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+y}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-y}\right|$ are complete but equivalent metrics on $G=(-1,1)$.

The definition of **equivalent** metrics is the following in my context: Two metrics are equivalent if **convergence** of any sequence in one metric implies the convergence of the other, and vise versa. By $\varepsilon-\delta$ approach (can be proven by argue by contradiction), $D_1$ and $D_2$ are equivalent on $G$ if and only if given $x\in G$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $y\in G$, $$D_1(x,y)<\delta\text{ implies }D_2(x,y)<\varepsilon\text{ and }D_2(x,y)<\delta\text{ implies }D_1(x,y)<\varepsilon$$

And I also know the fact **if two metrics are equivalent, and if one of them is complete, the other one do not have to be complete.**

My **first attempt** is to first prove that the two metrics are complete on $G=(-1,1)$, then prove that they are equivalent. But I'm not sure how to choose Cauchy sequences of $D_1$ and $D_2$ to make them complete. To prove them to be equivalence metrics, I'm not sure how to choose $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$.

My **second attempt** is to start from an incomplete metric on $(-1,1)$, and extend it to a complete metric by the following **method** on the same **open set**: if $G$ is an open set, and $d$ may not be a complete metric, we extend from $(G,d)$ to $(G,D)$, where the latter is a complete metric:

1. $$D(x,y)=d(x,y)+\left|\frac{1}{d(x,G^C)}-\frac{1}{d(y,G^C)}\right|$$

I use the fact that $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is not complete on $(-1,1)$, since if I take the Cauchy sequence $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$, but $x_n\to 1\notin(-1,1)$ (is this correct?). Then I'd like to apply the method I just mentioned to show that the two metrics are complete whilst equivalent. But I'm stuck here.

**Here are my questions:**

(a) For my **first attempt**, can anyone help me finish my argument, or at least give me sketches on how to choose Cauchy sequences and $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ to prove equivalence?

(b) For my **second attempt**, I'm trying to seek the relation between the standard metric on $(-1,1)$ and $D_1$ and $D_2$, then apply the completion method I just mentioned. But I'm not sure whether it is feasible. Can anyone follow my completion method?

I'll add more details if I have more progress. If there are mistakes, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Please avoid changing your question in a way that invalidates answers. Since I had already addressed one part of your question, you should not remove it.

Comment: @user21820: Sorry, I'll pay attention to that next time. With your explanation, I'm more comfortable understanding some gaps in previous author's post, and can come up with a proof regarding this.

Comment: I understand; it's just a kind of community thing so nothing to worry about. I'm very glad to hear that you have benefited from my answer. Feel free to inquiry more here or in chat! =)

Answer (score 2):

Let $d$ be the usual metric on $G$. By the convergence definition of metric equivalence, it suffices to show that for each $i=1,2$ any sequence $(x_n)$ of points of $G$ converges in $(G,D_i)$ to a point $x$ of $G$ iff $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in $(G,d)$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ It follows from an observation that $D_i(y,z)$ has a form $\sum |f_j(y)-f_j(z)|$ for some finite family of continuous functions on $(G,d)$ for each $y,z\in D$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ it follows from an inequality $D_i(y,z)\ge C_i d(y,z)$ for and some constant $C_i>0$ and each $y,z\in G$. Clearly, we can pick $C_2=1$.  We can pick $C_1=\tfrac{\pi}{2}$, because by Lagrange’s theorem for each $y,z\in G$ there exists $u$ between $y$ and $z$ such that $$\left|\tan \frac{\pi y}{2}-\tan \frac{\pi z}{2} \right|=\left|\left(\tan\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)’\right||y-z|=\left|\frac{\pi}{2\cos^2\tfrac{\pi u}{2} }\right||y-z|\ge \frac{\pi}{2}|y-z|.$$

It remains to show completeness of $(G, D_i)$ for each $i$.  Let $(x_n)$ be any Cauchy sequence in $(G, D_i)$. It is easy to see that for each $x\in G$, when $y\in G$ tends to $1$ or $-1$ in the usual metric on $[-1,1]$, then $D_i(x,y)$ tends to infinity. Therefore there eixists $H<1$ such that the sequence $(x_n)$ belongs to $[-H,H]$. Since $D_i(y,z)\ge C_i d(y,z)$ for each $y,z\in G$, it follows that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence on a compact metric subspace $[-H,H]$ of $(G,d)$. So $(x_n)$ converges in $(G,d)$ to some point $x\in H$. By the equivalence of metrics $D_i$ and $d$, $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in $(G,D_i)$ too.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. I have some questions regarding your answer: For showing equivalence, how do you show convergence from $D_1$ to $D_2$,and vise versa, since I do not see $D_2$ in your answer? When you are proving the sufficient side of equivalence, why can you use the inequality $D_i(y,z)\ge C_id(y,z)$? When showing completeness,  why does such inequality implies each $(G,D_i)$ is complete?

Comment: Another question: Is there an alternative way to prove this, which I listed as the second attempt in my original post? The method is laballed "1" by me. It basically turns an incomplete metric into a complete one under the same open set. I'm not sure whether this will work, but can you say such method is feasible?

Comment: @Mike For showing the equivalence, we show that both $D_1$ and $D_2$ are equivalent to $d$. The inequality $D_i(y,z)\ge C_id(y,z)$ assures that when $D_i(y,z)$ is small then $d(y,z)$ is small too, so the convergence of a sequence to $x$ with respect to $D_i$ implies its convergence to $x$ with respect to $d$.  But to show the completeness of $(G,D_i)$, we need to show somehow that sequence which is Cauchy in $(G,D_i)$ is convergent in $(G,d)$, and this is done at the end of the answer.

Comment: Another question is that why convergence in $(G,D_1)$ and $(G,D_2)$ is equivalent to convergence in $(G,d)$, where $d$ is the standard metric? Are there any proofs regarding this?

Comment: And for the necessary part for proving equivalence, can you expand your ideas a little bit? I don't quite understand why sum of continuous functions of the form $|f(x)-f(y)|$ implies convergence of $D_1$ and $D_2$ on $G=(-1,1)$, since the standard metric is not complete on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: I guess the derivative should be $|\frac{\pi}{2\cos^{2}\frac{\pi u}{2}}|$

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Thanks, fixed. Sorry for the misprint.

Answer (score 2):

First I must point out the logical flaw in your reasoning:

> But I'm not sure how to choose Cauchy sequences of D1 and D2 to make them complete.

As we discussed [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55726233#55726233), a metric space $(X,d)$ is complete iff ( for every sequence $f$ from $X$ such that $d(f(m),f(n)) → 0$ as $m,n→∞$, there is some $c∈X$ such that $d(f(n),c) → 0$ as $n→∞$ ). So to prove that $(X,d)$ is complete, you **do not get to choose** Cauchy sequences. A correct proof must instead always look like that:

Given any Cauchy sequence $f$ in $(X,d)$:
  $f : ℕ→X$ such that $d(f(m),f(n)) → 0$ as $m,n→∞$.
  ...
  Let $c∈X$ such that ...
  ...
  $d(f(n),c) → 0$ as $n→∞$.

The problem is, how to find such a $c$? The key to understanding the two given metric spaces is that, in both of them, moving the points apart in the standard metric (i.e. increasing $|x−y|$) increases their distance in the given metric (i.e. $d(x,y)$). This intuitively suggests that if $d(f(m),f(n)) → 0$, then $f(m)−f(n)$ → 0 as well. But this is not actually true in general, since $f(m),f(n)$ may not be moving strictly towards each other. One way to handle that is to grab a *fixed* reference point based on the standard metric: Let $c$ be the limit of *some* subsequence of $f$ that converges in the standard metric (by Bolzano-Weierstrass). Then $c ∈ [-1,1]$. But I claim that $c≠1$. Can you prove it? (Hint: Take any strictly increasing sequence $t : ℕ→ℕ$ such that $f(t(k)) → 1$ as $k→∞$. Then as $k→∞$ and $i,j≥k$, we have $d(f(t(i)),f(t(j))) → 0$, which is impossible since $d(f(t(i)),f(t(k))) → ∞$ as $n→∞$.) Similarly $c≠-1$. Also, I claim that $d(f(n),f(c)) → 0$ as $n→∞$. Try to prove it! (Hint: Let $t$ be some strictly increasing sequence $t : ℕ→ℕ$ such that $t(k) → c$ as $k→∞$. As $n→∞$, there is some $k>n$ such that $t(k)>n$, so $d(f(n),f(t(k))) → 0$ and $f(t(k)) → f(c)$.)

Comment: By the way, this approach of utilizing sequences instead of ε-δ definitions can be useful in matching intuitive reasoning in real analysis, as it is not 'backwards' (i.e. you don't have to go backwards from some error margin ε to some window δ). Of course, it is also good to translate the sequence-based proof to an ε-δ one just to make sure you fully understand how exactly the sequence usage succinctly captures a lot of the ε-δ reasoning.